# Difference between two date in excel excluding only holidays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im looking if there is a formula to calculate data difference in excel considering weekend but excluding holidays: For example I want to know how many days are from 1st of Jan 2017 to 15th of Jan 2017 giving a range of Holiday (i.e 7 of Jan and 08 of Jan)

Comment: Have a look at `NetworkDays` - `=NETWORKDAYS(start_date, end_date,[holidays])`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook He also wants weekends included. I don't know if there's a better way to do this, but a workaround could be to use the NETWORKDAYS formula and add COUNTIF(WEEKDAY()=1) and COUNTIF(WEEKDAY()=7)

Comment: I read it as excluding weekends.  You're right, will need extra to remove the weekends to.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NETWORKDAYS.INTL`.

`NETWORKDAYS.INTL(start_date, end_date, [weekend], [holidays])`

The optional `weekend` can be either a weekend number, or 7 character string of 0's and 1's showing which day the weekend is on.  1 = non-workday, 0=workday.

So with 1st Jan in A1, 15th Jan in A2, 7th Jan in F1, 8th Jan in F2:
`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A1,A2,"0000000",F1:F2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=E6-E5-COUNT(H1:H3)

E6 contains end date
E5 contains start date
H1:H3 contains lsit of holidays

Comment: That won't work.  If E6 is `10th January 2017`, E5 is `1st January 2017` and H1:H3 is `25th December 2015`,`Fred` & `5`.  It shouldn't remove those values as a holiday falling between the dates.

Comment: You could adapt this with a conditional count, e.g =E6-E5+1-COUNTIFS(H1:H3,">="&E5,H1:H3,"<="&E6)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
     =TEXT((B1-A1+1-NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1))+NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1,A3:A4),"d")

where,
A1 = start date,
B1 = end date,
A3 - A4 = list of holidays in between which can be any range
```